# Hack - how to check that an instance uses a Trait?

Tags: php, hacklang

How can I check if a an instance of a class uses a Trait? I can't use `instanceof` because the Trait is uninstantiable.

Comment: As an alternative, create an interface such as `HasTrait` and make all classes that use this trait implement this interface, then check that the class instance is an instance of this interface.

Answer (score 6):

Hack is a super set of PHP (and also a sub set, given some legacy stuff was removed), so most of the native functions can be used.

With that being said, you have the [class_uses()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.class-uses.php) function, that does what you want.

Here's a simplified use case:

```
if (in_array(\Foo\Bar::class, class_uses($object))) {
    // Do something if $object is using \Foo\Bar trait
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ReflectionObject](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionobject.php) with [getTraits](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.gettraits.php) or [getTraitNames](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.gettraitnames.php) functions:

```
trait test {
    public function hello()
    {
        echo "hello";
    }
}

class A {
    use test;
}

function hasTrait($object, $traitName)
{
    $reflection = new ReflectionObject($object);

    return in_array($traitName, $reflection->getTraitNames());
}

$a = new A();

if(hasTrait($a, 'test')) {
    echo "Object of class 'A' has 'test' trait \n";
}
```